# WordPress Bootstrap multilevel Vertical Menu

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, menu

I am working on two column bootstrap based WordPress theme where i want to implement multilevel Vertical menu.. After trying for hours somehow i have achieved success in creating responsive multilevel vertical menu in HTML/CSS for which i have shared the code below. I want to implement it in WordPress nav-menu. The issue that i am facing is the sub-menu overlaps the parent menu links in bottom instead of working just like the html code that i have created and added. I know i need to work with navwalker which i tried but was unable to get success. Can you please tell me how can i achieve the same menu functionality as per the given code in WordPress nav-menu.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="site-logo hidden-xs"><h2>Company Logo</h2></div>
<div class="sidebar-nav">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Company Logo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="btn-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="pull-right"><b class="caret"></b></span></a>
        <ul class="nav collapse" id="submenu1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1">         
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="btn-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu2" aria-expanded="false">Sub-Dropdown <span class="pull-right"><b class="caret"></b></span></a>
            <ul class="nav collapse" id="submenu2" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-2">         
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li></ul>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDEL**](https://jsfiddle.net/johnysntg/r9qd973f/)

Comment: can you post navwalker code tried so far?

Comment: i used the navwalker by Edward https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired menu by removing floats from the Bootstrap navbar, and setting `position: static` on the dropdown menu, plus a few other styling tweaks.

Then you have to do a little JavaScript to get the nested dropdown menus to work.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlerjason/55e1ugr3/3/).

JavaScript courtesy of [W3Schools snippet](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h).

Comment: I built my JSFiddle using the Bootstrap navbar, and the mobile toggle button works. I looked at your page code and don't see the Bootstrap JS being loaded. Maybe try loading that and see if that's what makes the button work?

Comment: Cool, i created a page template to test whether it works or not and forgot to include footer which is why it was not showing some enqueued scripts .. Now everything is working absolutely fine.. Thanks again.. You saved my hours OR may be days..